How can I get the position of an element using Velo?
I want to get the position of a vector element and a button relative to the window using Wix Velo. I tried the following code:
let element = $w('#vector1');
let rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();

How can I get the position of an element using Velo?

What is $w? jQueryWTF? Define element this way: const element = document.getElementById("vector1")

Or if you actually have jQuery: const element = $("#vector1")  (not $w), but you'll need to dereference it like so: element[0] or element.get(0).

@zer00ne $w seems to be correct, it's exclusive to Wix.

@jawher Please include enough code for readers to run and debug. Also provide what's your expectation and what's currently wrong.

@zer00ne It’s for the Wix API, not jQuery or anything else

@LãNgọcHải It was the maximum number of lines of code, What I’m actually trying to achieve is this:
I created an HTML embed that moves with the scroll of the window.
I want this element to stop scrolling when it reaches the position of the Vector element.
To ensure it remains properly responsive on all screens, I need to get the position of the Vector element relative to the window.
The getBoundingRect method from wixWindowFrontend provides information about the window, document, and scroll position,
but not about a specific element on the screen.
I’m trying hard to find a solution

@jawher I just took at quick glance at the docs and found .getBoundingRect() returns a promise.

@LãNgọcHải getBoundingRect method from wixWindowFrontend provides information about the window, document, and scroll position, but not about a specific element on the screen

I don't know much about wix so I can't make answer, though you can check this similiar question for some ideas. If you can provide the error log and the html/js output it would be a lot easier to check what's wrong.
